# Safari flexbox text wrapping issue

Tags: css, safari, flexbox, word-wrap

I've discovered an issue with Safari (OS X): 
https://codepen.io/alexlouden/pen/jONyZKb

```js
document
  .querySelectorAll('.parent')
  .forEach(el => {
    el.addEventListener("mouseover", event => {
      event.target.style.color = 'blue';
    })
  })
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.parent {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 280px;
  padding: 32px;
  background-color: #e99;
  margin: 32px;
  text-align: center;
}
.child {
  flex: 1;
  max-width: 100%;
  background-color: #99e;
}
.grandchild {
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  border: 1px dotted black;
}
```

```html
<div>
  In Safari, when you hover on the red area the XXXs will stop wrapping. <br/>
  Hover over the blue area and it will fix and re-wrap.
</div>

<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <div class="grandchild">
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <div class="grandchild">
Centered
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The `grandchild` seems to not be respecting the max-width constraint of the `child`, but only when the style of the parent is modified - not when it's first loaded.

I'm wondering what's causing this behaviour, and whether this is already a known issue with Safari or if I should report the bug?

Comment: Instead of setting the child to `flex: 1; max-width: 100%`, have you tried the full flex equivalent? Remove those two lines and try `flex: 0 1 100%`.

Comment: @Michael_B thanks for the idea! I just tried `flex: 0 1 100%`, `flex: 1 0 100%` (also both with `flex-basis: auto` just for good measure) and none of them cause the text to wrap: https://imgur.com/a/0R23FpR. The only thing that seems to get the text to wrap at all is to add either `min-width`, `width` or `max-width`, but they seem to all be susceptible to the bug above!

Comment: You tried `min-width: 0` on the `.child`?

Comment: @Michael_B Yeah I'm afraid so - no luck! Sorry for the delayed reply!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess answer is much simpler then I thought ':D !!

Just change the following css and it should work B)

```
.parent {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 280px;
  padding: 32px;
  background-color: #e99;
  margin: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: Hi Prajyot, thanks for your answer! I think the reason your answer doesn't trigger the bug is that you only modify the style for the `.grandchild` rather than the `.parent` - so the parent's styles aren't recalculated. (You can see this if you change your JS to be `$(this).css(` instead). In my real app the parent style is getting modified, which causes the layout issue, so I'm afraid I need a solution that doesn't modify the JS at all, just the CSS!

Comment: Ahh thanks for the update - adding `overflow-wrap` to the parent seems to work! How bizarre! Thank you again!